# Ctools modal_form not working with webforms

Tags: forms, chaos-tool-suite

i have been trying all morning to get my webform to open up within ctools modal_forms popup window. i’ve tried *everything*, but nothing has worked so far.

the module is working no problem. this form window displays as expected.

```
mywebsite.com/modal_forms/nojs/register
```

and my webform is published and working

```
mywebsite.com/webform/free-trial
```

but when viewing docs and tuts on the module,  the URL would seem to be

```
mywebsite.com/modal_forms/nojs/webform_free-trial
```

i’ve also manually created links such as this

```
<a class="ctools-use-modal" href="/modal_forms/nojs/webform/free-trial">Modal Login</a>

<a class="ctools-use-modal" href="/webform/free-trial">Modal Login</a>
```

even went to the config page and set,

PAGE ACTIVATION SETTINGS/Only the listed pages

```
webform/free-trial
```

Mondo Aggro! any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to create your own menu item where you should load and print the webform using examples from the ctools module.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your modal link path isn't correct. When using Webforms the link needs to use the Node ID (nid), not the form clean-url (`/modal_forms/nojs/webform/[nid]`) Here's how the link would look considering your example above:

```
<a class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-modal-popup-large" href="/modal_forms/nojs/webform/123123">Free Trial</a>
```